# Trello bug?  - Invited members not shown in a board

Tags: trello

I created a new organization in trello, invited another co-worker, and his name has been to the organization, however, in a board which is visible to the entire organization I created earlier I couldn't see his name nor I can assign a card to him. Is this a bug?

Comment: You many want to contact Trello to solve this seeing that the solution below doesn't help you.

Answer (score 2):

While the board may be **visible** to the entire organization, if you someone to **participate** on a board (i.e. to be able to create cards and have things assigned to them) you'll also need to make them a board member, by clicking "**Add Members...**".

Comment: Unfortunately, the "Add Members..." command inside the board doesn't list other members in the org except me...